# Its getting logout, but session not getting expire

Tags: php, session

The below one is the link in my php site.. after clicking this button the user's session should be terminated and came to login page.

But the session not getting expire.

```
<?php
$logoutGoTo = "../index.php";
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
if ($logoutGoTo != "") {header("Location: $logoutGoTo");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Try adding `session_destroy();`

Comment: unset should be enough, you might do some weird stuff in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use this function

```
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score -1):

Logout should not just go to index.php just like that please let it go to logout page: that you have applied the dreamweaver logout server behaviour it contains a line of code to

```
`session_destroy(); or unset($_SESSION);`
Your index.php should also be able to regenerate_id();


if ((isset($_GET['doLogout'])) &&($_GET['doLogout']=="true")){
  //to fully log out a visitor we need to clear the session varialbles
  $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = NULL;
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = NULL;
  unset($_SESSION['MM_Username']);
  unset($_SESSION['MM_UserGroup']);
  unset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']);
```

i think, hope this helps.